# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError while running linear svm with One-vs-Rest model

Tags: java, apache-spark, svm, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to train the model using linear SVM. I am having nearly 300 classes but need to run it with SVM so I used the one vs rest(OvR) approach. I am using apache spark with java. While running it with OvR I am getting the bellow error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.builder$1(TraversableLike.scala:229)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.AbstractSet.scala$collection$SetLike$$super$map(Set.scala:47)
at scala.collection.SetLike$class.map(SetLike.scala:92)
at scala.collection.AbstractSet.map(Set.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeSet.foreach(AttributeSet.scala:120)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:590)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeSet.to(AttributeSet.scala:60)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeSet.toBuffer(AttributeSet.scala:60)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.toStream(TraversableLike.scala:585)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeSet.toStream(AttributeSet.scala:60)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Stream.scala:497)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Stream.scala:497)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.append(Stream.scala:255)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:255)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:255)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1233)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1223)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Stream.scala:497)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Stream.scala:497)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.append(Stream.scala:255)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:255)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:255)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1233)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1223)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1233)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1223)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.loop$1(Growable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:57)
at scala.collection.mutable.SetBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(SetBuilder.scala:20)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:590)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:104)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toSet(TraversableOnce.scala:304)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toSet(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeSet$.apply(AttributeSet.scala:45)
```

Here is the code I used:

```
LinearSVC sv = new LinearSVC()
    .setMaxIter(10)
    .setRegParam(0.001)
    .setLabelCol(LABEL)
    .setFeaturesCol("features");

OneVsRest ovr = new OneVsRest().setClassifier(sv);

Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(new PipelineStage[] {
          labelIndexer,
          tokenizer, 
          numberNormalizer,
          remover, 
          wordVectorizer, 
          idf,
          ovr,
          deIndexer
      });

    long trainStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Fit the pipeline to training documents.
    PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(training);
```